# Changing ulimit on ubuntu 12.04 Never works

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hadoop, ulimit, limits

I am working with hadoop and need to change number of open files `ulimit -n`. I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere and have tried everything in those answers, but it still does not work. I am working with `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. Here is what i have done:

change limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, i have put in settings for * and `root`. I have also changed  limits to some number like `10000` and `unlimited`.

```
* soft nofile 1513687
* hard nofile 1513687
root soft nofile 1513687
root hard nofile 1513687
```

I have also tried above setting with `-` instead of `soft` and `hard`. After these changes, i have made changes to `/etc/pam.d/` files such as:

```
common-session 
common-session-noninterative
login
cron
sshd
su
sudo
```

i have added `session required pam_limits.so` to the beginning of each file. I made a restart of the box in question and the settings did not take effect.

I have also found that there were files inside `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory for the users `hbase` `mapred` and `hdfs`. I have tried changing limits in these individual files as well to no avail.

I have tried putting `ulimit -S -n unlimited` inside `/etc/profile` as well. It did not work.

Finally, i have tried putting `limit nofile unlimited unlimited` inside `/etc/init.d/hadoop*` files as first line. Did not work.

One interesting thing though is, i do not have hbase installed on the box but i do have a `hbase.conf` file inside `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory. The settings in this file are reflected with `ulimit -n`. But settings from `hdfs.conf` and `mapred.conf` are not reflected. Which suggests that something is overwriting settings for `hdfs` and `mapred`.

I guess i have tried everything people suggested on several forums, is there anything else that i may have missed or done incorrectly?

I am using `CDH 4.4.0` as my hadoop distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reboot? I found the changes in /etc/security/limits.conf only work for me after reboot.

Comment: You can set the ulimits of running processes using `prlimit`  on kernels >= 2.6.36.

Comment: yes, i did reboot and it did not work. i will givr prlimit a try but ideally i want these settings to be permanent.

Comment: What's the indicator that makes you determine that it does not work?